# Browsing without address bar, buttons, and other stuff

Tags: google-chrome, browser, tabs, address-bar

After searching this site, I found a similar question which is almost identical to mine (https://superuser.com/questions/459775/how-can-i-launch-a-browser-with-no-window-frame-or-tabs-address-bar), except that I need a bit more.

I also want to launch ANY browser without tabs, buttons, and address bar. I want browser to have its main window (so Minimize, Maximize, and Close buttons are displayed) and nothing else (scrollbars are OK when page is long).

I was able to launch Chrome using "chrome.exe --app=http://google.com" command, but there is a problem - when I move mouse over any link on website, Chrome displays URL in left bottom corner. If I can prevent it from being displayed, everything would be perfect.

Can someone recommend me a solution? It can be based on ANY browser.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of research I figured out this is impossible because all the browsers will display balloons (with link/form URL) for security reasons. The only possible solution is to write a custom browser and embed any engine (like IE or Chrome) into it. This is what I had to do to get the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use Chrome's Kios Mode. Run chrome with "kiosk" argument like this: `chrome.exe --kios {url}`